# How to make RingCentral sandbox calls with recording

Tags: java, ringcentral, call-recording

I have a RingCentral developer account but I am unable to successfully establish a call. Furthermore I would also like the call to be recorded, so that later I can access the call logs and recording.

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest ways to place test calls is through RingCentral's "softphone" [1]. This is an app for your desktop that has the functionality you require. You can place calls, and record calls as well. It also gives you access to your call log, and call recordings. This can be helpful if you need to reconcile what you see via the API. (FYI - it may take 30-60 for recordings to appear in this app, as the system needs to store and encode the recording for playback first.)

The RingCentral phone can be toggled to work against the RingCentral sandbox environment as well. That way you can place calls in our test environment as you build your application. To toggle to sandbox, after you log in, press Ctrl+F2 (for PC) or Fn+Cmd+F2 (for a Mac). This will bring up a menu to select your preferred environment.

[1] https://www.ringcentral.com/apps/rc-phone

Answer (score 0):

The RingCentral mobile app as I can see does not support sandbox mode. But still you can use the RingCentral [soft phone](https://www.ringcentral.com/office/features/softphone/overview.html?BMID=GGECUSEP&CID=sem&RCCN=Google_US_Search_Brand_Exact&RCAG=AAA_Brand_Softphone_%5BExact%5D&RCKW=ringcentral%20softphone%20download&RCMT=e&AD=247338666465&mkwid=s%7Cpcrid%7C247338666465%7Cpkw%7Cringcentral%20softphone%20download%7Cpmt%7Ce%7Cpdv%7Cc%7Cslid%7C%7C&pgrid=62589705785&ptaid=kwd-59221909572&st-t=&gclid=CjwKCAiAo8jgBRAVEiwAJUXKqJVRpkXC7aImea8VQ71eNY8d8FWEYHiWd5oRaJfLFq_Sfa1wUl6gCRoCbtIQAvD_BwE) and switch the soft phone to sandbox mode before login with your sandbox credentials.

**On Windows:** Ctrl + F2
**On Mac OS:** Fn + Command + F2

If you wish to create call recordings programmatically, there is an GitHub app that will help you:

https://github.com/anilkumarbp/Sample-Demo-to-Download-Call-Recordings

other source you can refer: https://developers.ringcentral.com/guide/call-log/manual/recordings

ref from similar question: https://forums.developers.ringcentral.com/questions/1367/how-to-enable-call-recording-in-sandbox-environmen.html