# Can we record call in RingCentral sandbox

Tags: ringcentral, call-recording

I was exploring ringcentral developer account and I have a sandbox environment.  But after exploring all the API documentation I was unable to find out if I can call and record the call in sandbox. Which I can use once the call is over.

If call recording is possible can we record an ongoing call I don't find in any documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Recording feature is not turned on by default in Sandbox profile.
RingCentral's softphone or desktop app can be used to test that.
The RingCentral mobile app as I can see does not support sandbox mode. But still you can use the RingCentral soft phone and switch the soft phone to sandbox mode before login with your sandbox credentials.

```
On Windows: Ctrl + F2
On Mac OS: Fn + Command + F2
```

If you wish to create call recordings programmatically, there is an GitHub app that will help you:

https://github.com/anilkumarbp/Sample-Demo-to-Download-Call-Recordings

It takes some time to finish and make the recording available around 30 sec after the call.
You can also refer answer for your question
[How to make RingCentral sandbox calls with recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54802127/how-to-make-ringcentral-sandbox-calls-with-recording)

Comment: Understood, thanks.. I already have desktop app, will try with that